# Video Processing using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-streaming, video-processing

I'm using a streaming platform (daCast) to stream live videos from which I get a link to a video player like this https://iframe.dacast.com/b/109990/c/470023

I want to extract frames from the live video. Is this achievable with opencv?

(My plan B is to use selenium to take actual screenshots of the player but I'm hoping to find a more elegant solution)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It's very strange that streaming platform doesn't have an option for parallel streaming to web and making local recording.
I use XSplit package for video streaming to youtube. This package is able to create virtual usb web cam (MS DirectShow compatible). OpenCV works perfectly with usb web cam. By the way, basic license of XSplit is absolutely free